# How can I get 2 or more animations to work in a single div with UIKit?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, animation, uikit

I am working on a to-do web application and I wanted to make it look nicer with some animations from UIKit. Right now, I have an animation that toggles when the `todo-items` gets put into view:

`<div class="todo-items uk-animation-toggle uk-animation-scale-up" tabindex="0" :id="style.id">`

Where `style.id` changes based on the todo item.

I also have a checkmark that moves the todo item to the completed section of the webpage:

`<input type="checkbox" uk-toggle :target="style.target" animation="uk-animation-scale-up uk-animation-reverse" mode="click" @click="completedTask">`

However, the animation for that checkmark does not seem to work when there is already an animation for the block when it initially appears. The topmost toggle animation takes precedence and the checkmark animation does not work. If I remove the topmost animation, the checkmark works as intended, it is when there are two when it does not work.

This is a template from a Vue.js component:

```
<div class="todo-items uk-animation-toggle uk-animation-scale-up" tabindex="0" :id="style.id">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1-10">
                <div class="center">
                    <input type="checkbox" uk-toggle :target="style.target" animation="uk-animation-scale-up uk-animation-reverse" mode="click" @click="completedTask">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-7-10">
                <h3>Task {{ count + 1 }}</h3>
                <p v-show="!edit" @click="editTask">{{ description }}</p>
                <input v-show="edit" v-model="description" @keyup.enter="editTask">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2-10">
                <div class="center">
                    <button @click="editTask">{{ edit ? "Done" : "Edit" }}</button>
                    <button @click="deleteTask" id="deleteButton">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the whole component if needed:

```
Vue.component('todo-item', {
    props: {
        count: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        index: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    },
    template:
    `
    <div class="todo-items uk-animation-toggle uk-animation-scale-up" tabindex="0" :id="style.id">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1-10">
                <div class="center">
                    <input type="checkbox" uk-toggle :target="style.target" animation="uk-animation-scale-up uk-animation-reverse" mode="click" @click="completedTask">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-7-10">
                <h3>Task {{ count + 1 }}</h3>
                <p v-show="!edit" @click="editTask">{{ description }}</p>
                <input v-show="edit" v-model="description" @keyup.enter="editTask">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2-10">
                <div class="center">
                    <button @click="editTask">{{ edit ? "Done" : "Edit" }}</button>
                    <button @click="deleteTask" id="deleteButton">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    `,
    data() {
        return {
            edit: false,
            style: {
                id: 'task' + this.index,
                'target': '#task' + this.index,
                'animation': 'uk-animation-scale-up uk-animation-reverse',
                'slideRight': 'uk-animation-slide-right uk-animation-reverse',
                'mode': 'click',
                'duration': 400
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        completedTask() { 
            setTimeout(() => this.$emit('complete-task', this.index), this.style.duration);
        },
        deleteTask() {
            this.$emit('remove-task', this.index);
        },
        editTask() {
            this.edit = !this.edit;
            if (!this.edit) {
                this.$emit('edit-task', this.description, this.index);
            }
            
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: sorry to highjack the comments but you opened and deleted a question regarding Azure Data Studio, may I ask if you could reopen it and tell how did you solve the issue? I encountered the same issue after opening my project in Visual Studio.

Comment: @adrien I deleted the question because I was told that StackOverflow was not the right place to ask a question about a software, just code.

The way I solved it is by clicking on the parent folder of the folder I wanted to add a SQL file to and gave it a direct path. 

For example, if I have `foo/bar/` and I wanted to add a new file in `bar/` called `table.sql`, I would click on `foo`, select add table, and for the name I would write `bar/table.sql` and that seemed to solve it for me. Let me know if you have any questions about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's impossible. The alternative is remove the previous animation when it's finished.

```html
<div
  class="todo-items uk-animation-toggle"
  :class="animationEnter ? 'uk-animation-scale-up' : ''"
  :id="style.id"
  tabindex="0">
  ...
</div>
```

```js
...
  mounted () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.animationEnter = false
    }, 500)
  }
...
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/8q576ndz/)

Or use Vue [List-Transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions) which is reliable and easier:

```html
<transition-group
  name='list'
  tag='div'
  appear
  enter-active-class='uk-animation-scale-up'
  leave-active-class='uk-animation-scale-up uk-animation-reverse'>
  <todo-item
    v-for='item in todoItems'
    :key='item.id'
    ...>
  </todo-item>
</transition-group>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/d243ogtx/)